# Sanitize users inputs before saving or sanitize inputs after retrieving from the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, xss

I want to save the users inputs into my database but I am unsure if I should sanitize the user inputs before saving to the database or after I get them from the database and display them in the HTML?

**Like here(before saving):**

```js
var topic=htmlencode.htmlEncode(req.body.topic);
var topiccontent=req.body.topiccontent;
var z=markdown.toHTML(topiccontent);
   var clean = sanitizeHtml(z, {
  allowedTags: ['b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','img','blockquote','code','br'],
  allowedAttributes: {'a': [ 'href','alt','title' ],'img':['src','alt','title']},
  
  allowedIframeHostnames: []
});
var opentopic=new topics({topic:topic,topiccontent:topiccontent,writerid:req.session.id,tür:tür,begeni:0,writernick:req.session.nick});
```

**And(sanitize inputs from database)here:**

```js
topics.findOne({topic:req.query.w},function(err,topic){
var topic=htmlencode.htmlEncode(topic.topic);

var topiccontent=topic.topiccontent;

var y=markdown.toHTML(topiccontent);
   var clean = sanitizeHtml(y, {
  allowedTags: ['b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','img','blockquote','code','br'],
  allowedAttributes: {'a': [ 'href','alt','title' ],'img':['src','alt','title']},
  
  allowedIframeHostnames: []
});
res.render('./show',{topic:topic,topiccontent:topiccontent....})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection):

*As a client program assembles a query in MongoDB, it builds a BSON object, not a string. Thus traditional SQL injection attacks are not a problem.*

So "sanitizing" the users input before storing it in the database is not required like it would be in MySQL however there are some injection techniques which are relative to MongoDB that you should do some research about on.

That being said, it would make sense because you want to do this before displaying the users input, as I am sure that you understand this is very important too.

Think about it this way, if you "sanitize" the value before you save it then you only have to compute this result once. However, if you do this every time that you fetch it from the database and display it for the user then you're computing the result unlimited amount of times and ultimately slowing down the users access to the end result.

Also note the [Javascript part of the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#javascript):

*All of the following MongoDB operations permit you to run arbitrary JavaScript expressions directly on the server:*

```
$where
mapReduce
group
```

*You must exercise care in these cases to prevent users from submitting malicious JavaScript.*

Comment: Firstly ty @craig.So I need more memory- if i sanitize inputs before saving.Like this example `**come**`=8 byte ;but markdown.toHTML(`**come**`)=>result is <span style="font-style:bold">come</span>=41 byte

Comment: So i must choose speed or memory :D

Comment: @ŞükranEken Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way, I hope that you will become more active here. Yes but you must also be careful how you make use of the users input. I made a small edit to my answer from: `Think about it this way` and I hope it makes even more sense for you.